# Why does recognition rate drop after multiple online training epochs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, mnist

I am using tensorflow to do image recognition on the MNIST dataset. In each training epoch, I picked 10,000 random images and conducted online training with batch size of 1. The recognition rate increased for the first few epochs, however, after several epochs the recognition rate started to drop greatly. (In the first 20 epochs, the recognition rate goes up to ~94%. Afterwards, the recognition rate went from 90->50->40->30->20). What is the reason for this?

Also, with a batch size of 1, the performance is worse than when using a batch size of 100 (max recognition rate 94% vs. 96%). I looked through several references but there seems to be contradictory results on whether small or large batch sizes achieve better performance. What would be this case in this situation?

Edit: I also added a figure of the recognition rate of the training dataset and the test dataset.[Recognition rate vs. epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jEM8.jpg)

I have attached a copy of the code below. Thanks for the help!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)

#parameters
n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500
n_classes = 10
batch_size = 1
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

#model of neural network
def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])               , name='l1_w'),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1])                    , name='l1_b')}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])       , name='l2_w'),
                      'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2])                    , name='l2_b')}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])       , name='l3_w'),
                      'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3])                    , name='l3_b')}

    output_layer   = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])     , name='lo_w'),
                      'biases' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])                   , name='lo_b')}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1) 
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)     
    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)
    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']    
return output

#train neural network
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
    hm_epoches = 100
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epoches):
            epoch_loss=0
            for batch in range (10000):
                epoch_x, epoch_y=mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)                
                _,c =sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x:epoch_x, y:epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
            print(epoch_loss)
            print('Accuracy_test:', accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))
            print('Accuracy_train:', accuracy.eval({x:mnist.train.images, y:mnist.train.labels}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: It's weird that the training error and test error lines are tracking each other so closely; are you sure those sets are non-overlapping?

Comment: @Ray Yes, according to the tensorflow function (mnist.train.next_batch),  only data from the training set is picked. I think the main reason for this phenomenon (training dataset recognition rate closely following testing dataset) is that for each epoch, I don't train with the entire training dataset, but rather with a subset of the training set (10k random data points). What may result from using the same dataset for training and testing? Will it have possibly caused this decline in recognition?

Comment: No, that wouldn't cause the decline in recognition; it would just make the results useless, since it's trivial (for certain values of trivial) to get 100% recognition on a training set if you don't need to generalize to unseen data.

Answer (score 2):

**DROPPING ACCURACY**

You're over-fitting.  This is when the model learns false features that are specific to artifacts of the images in the training data, at the expense of important features.  One of the main experimental results of any application is to determine the optimal number of training iterations.

For instance, perhaps 80% of the 7's in your training data *happen* to have a little extra slant to the right near the bottom of the stem, where 4's and 1's do not.  After *too much* training, your model "decides" that the best way to tell a 7 from another digit is from that extra slant, despite any other features.  As a result, some 1's and 4's now get classed as 7's.

**BATCH SIZE**

Again, the best batch size is one of the experimental results.  Typically, a batch size of 1 is too small: this gives the first few input images too much influence on the early weights in kernel or perceptron training.  This is a minor case of over-fitting: one item having undue influence on the model.  However, it's significant enough to alter your best results by 2%.

You need to balance the batch size with the other hyper-parameters to find the model's "sweet spot", optimum performance followed by shortest training time.  In my experience, it's been best to increase the batch size until my time per image degraded.  The models I've used most (MNIST, CIFAR-10, AlexNet, GoogleNet, ResNet, VGG, etc.) had very little loss of accuracy once we reached a rather minimal batch size; from there, the training speed was usually a matter of choosing the batch size the best used available RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I originally thought this may be a result of over-fitting, but when overfitting happens the recognition rate of the training data set should generally be very high. In my experiment, the recognition rate of the training dataset also goes down to ~20%. I didn't make that clear in the question. Is there a possible cause for this?

Comment: Agreed.  When over-fitting is the culprit, the training set rate should keep climbing.  Shuffling the data set is important in any case; changing the activation function is a good idea.  Also consider inserting a drop-out layer, if you have the capacity to do so.

Comment: @Ray, you might consider deleting these comments and writing a full answer.  They're worthy of better visibility.

Comment: @Prune Probably a good idea.  Originally I was just mentioning validation sets as an addendum to your answer, but my comments do seem to have grown beyond that.

Comment: @Prune I think tensorflow does shuffle the dataset, so I'll change the activation function and try the dropout layer.  I edited the question to attach a graph of the recognition rate on the training dataset and the test dataset. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities, although you'll need to do some experimentation to find out which it is.

**Overfitting**

Prune did a good job of explaining this.  I'll add that the simplest way to avoid overfitting is to just remove 10-15% of the training set and evaluate the recognition rate on this held out validation set after every few epochs. If you graph the change in recognition rate on both the training and validation sets, you'll eventually reach a point on the graph where the training error keeps going down but the validation error starts going up. Stop training at that point; that's where overfitting is starting in earnest. Note that it's important that there be no overlap between the training/validation/test sets.

This was more likely before you mentioned that the training error wasn't also decreasing, but it's possible that it's overfitting on a fairly homogeneous part of your training set at the expense of the outliers, or something like this.  Try randomizing the order of your training set after each epoch; if it's fitting one section of the set at the expense of the others, this might help.

Addendum: The massive instantaneous drop in quality around epoch 20 makes this even less likely; that is not what overfitting looks like.

**Numerical Instability**

If you get a particularly incorrect input at a point on the activation function with a large gradient, it's possible to end up with a gigantic weight update that screws up everything it's learned thus far.  It's common to put a hard limit on the gradient magnitude for this reason.  But you're using AdamOptimizer, which has an epsilon parameter for avoiding instability.  I haven't read the paper it references, so I don't know exactly how it works, but the fact that it's there makes instability less likely.

**Saturated Neurons**

Some activation functions have regions with very small gradients, so if you end up with weights such that the function is almost always in that region, you have a tiny gradient and thus can't learn effectively.  Sigmoids and Tanh are particularly prone to this since they have flat regions on both sides of the function.  ReLUs don't have a flat region on the high end, but do on the low end.  Try replacing your activation functions with Softplus; those are similar to ReLU, but with a continuous nonzero gradient.